# Problem in combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

I am having hard time solving following problem: you are given 32-card deck (4 suits, 4 aces). You draw cards until you draw an ace or 4 cards have been drawn.
Find probability that no black cards have been drawn. The solution is 10.1% (it could be wrong though).

My attempt: consider 4 cases $\approx$ 16%:

1. red ace is drawn as 1st card $\frac{2 \choose 1}{32 \choose 1}$
2. red non-ace card is drawn followed by red ace $\frac{{14 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}}{{28 \choose 1}{31 \choose 1}}$
3. 2 red non-ace cards are drawn followed by red ace $\frac{{14 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}}{{28 \choose 2}{30 \choose 1}}$
4. 3 red non-ace cards are drawn followed by  any red card $\frac{{14 \choose 3}{13 \choose 1}}{{28 \choose 3}{29 \choose 1}}$

The solution is sum of probabilities of those cases.

However my peers get this as solution: $\frac{2 \choose 1}{32 \choose 1}$ + $\frac{{14 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}}{{32 \choose 2}}$ + $\frac{{14 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}}{{32 \choose 3}}$ + $\frac{{14 \choose 3}{13 \choose 1}}{{32 \choose 4}}$ $\approx$ 28.7%.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you draw your first card from the deck of 32 cards, what is the probability that it is a red non-ace?

Comment: Why do you have all those 28s in it denominators?  The denominators are supposed to be all possible cases.  So those should be 32s as you can draw any of 32 cards.

Comment: It's because if I draw a red ace i should stop drawing cards.So I can only choose from non-ace cards.

Answer (score 0):

Your peers are closer to correct, but still wrong.

Better to think of it as always drawing four cards, and determining the probability that no black card comes before a red ace (or at all, assuming the no red ace is drawn.)

The odds of getting a red ace in the first round is:

$$\frac{2\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}$$

The odds of getting a red non-ace in the first card and a red ace in the second:

$$\frac{14\cdot 2\cdot 30\cdot 29}{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}$$

The odds of getting two red non-aces then a red ace:

$$\frac{14\cdot 13\cdot 2\cdot 29}{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}$$

Three red non-aces and then any red card:

$$\frac{14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 13}{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}$$

Your peers can fix their answer by taking:

$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{32}{1}}+\frac{\binom{14}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{2\binom{32}{2}}+\frac{\binom{14}{2}\binom{2}{1}}{3\binom{32}{3}}+\frac{\binom{14}{4}}{\binom{32}{4}}+\frac{\binom{14}{3}\binom{2}{1}}{4\binom{32}{4}}$$

They are forgetting that the denominator needs to represent picking them in order with a specified last card, so if the red ace is the $n$th card, we have to multiply the denominator by $n$. This is clearer, though, with my alternative formulation above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what buggles me is that you always use 32⋅31⋅30⋅29 as denominator. That implies that you could draw red ace and keep drawing cards after. Or I am simply wrong.

Comment: As I said at the beginning, think of it as always drawing the four cards. As you can see, my answer cancels out - you get:$$\frac{2}{32}+\frac{14\cdot 2}{32\cdot 31} + \frac{14\cdot 13\cdot 2}{32\cdot 31\cdot 30}+\frac{14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 13}{32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29}$$

Comment: Sorry for me being pain in the neck. Let's assume that you actually want to messure this empirically. Than this term $\frac{14⋅13⋅12⋅13}{32⋅31⋅30⋅29}$ is not consistent with reality because it implies that multiple   drawn aces are possible. Consider this instead: $\frac{14⋅13⋅12⋅13}{28⋅27⋅26⋅29}$. I am not saying you are not correct, it's just not clear to me.

Comment: Good luck! It is tricky, but I'm a bit busy right now, so someone else will have to explain it further, or you'll have to wait for a few hours.

Comment: That last fraction is the probability of drawing four cards, in order, such that the first three are red non-aces and the fourth is red. The total number of permutations is 32x31x30x29. The number of those which start with three red non-aces followed by a fourth red card is, by multiplication principle, 14x13x12x13.   (14 red non-aces for the first card, then 13 remaining, then 12, and then 13 red cards remaining for the last choice). The last card must be red but could be an ace or a non-ace.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to subtract from $1$ the probability that you *do* wind up drawing a black card.  I.e.,

$$1-\left({16\over32}+{14\over32}{16\over31}+{14\over32}{13\over31}{16\over30}+{14\over32}{13\over31}{12\over30}{16\over29}\right)\approx13.585\%$$

Incidentally, when I evaluate your peers' solution, I get $28.7\%$

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake, I corrected it.  Thanks. But I have the same problem as with the previous answer. I might be a bit confused since I am relatively new to this subject. I don't understand why you choose from 32 cards rather than from 28.

Comment: @Anterior, you are starting with the complete deck of $32$ cards.  In my calculation, the probability that you draw a black card on the first draw is $16/32$, because $16$ of the $32$ available cards are black.  (This assumes, of course, that half the cards are black and half are red.  The problem doesn't explicitly say that that's the case.  I'd be curious to know which $20$ cards have been eliminated from the standard deck of $52$....)

Comment: you have 7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A in each suit